# how get type of input based on another input in typescript

Tags: typescript

let think we have this function

```js
const myFn = (
    foo: Record<string, any>,
    bar: Record<keyof typeof foo, any>,
) => {
    return { foo, bar }
}
```

and we want to set bar object keys based on foo object keys. but typescript doesn't throw any error for that.

look at this

```js
myFn({ one: 'noghint', two: 'nothing' }, { three: 'nothing' })
```

it should throw an error for the second parameter of myFn because the key of the second object is set to none of the keys inside the first object.

is there any way to use a generic type of typescript?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that using [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content). If the second parameter does not require all keys of the first parameter use the [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility type.

```
const myFn = <
  T extends Record<string, any>,
  U extends Record<keyof T, any>
  /* U extends Partial<Record<keyof T, any>>*/
>(
  foo: T,
  bar: U
) => {
  return {foo, bar};
};

myFn({one: "nothing", two: "nothing"}, {three: "nothing"});
//                                      ~~~~~
// Argument of type '{ three: string; }' is not assignable to ...
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGJhgXhgHgLACgYwAqMApgB5QlgAmEMASiaAE7WbTMCWYA5gDQwAhmAQA%20PngIBVUhSq0GTEK0wBrEghAAzIgOFi8ogBSSYWkCABcu0wCNBza1LwBKdKJgBvU8xJQArsyonuYgAvbMAL4A3HgxeHiIKEae4CTWAERgIFAAFtw8GQJQAO5WMFk5%20bwZkQKeeb7pFdl5BbUu0UA)